# parsing issues in corrupted json using python

Tags: python, json, quotes

I have a corrupted json, like following:

```
{'a': 'b', 'c': "abcd'efgh ijklm"}
```

Before using python json.loads, i need to do 2 things:

1. replace single quote inside double quote with `\'`
2. replace all other single quote, except `\'` with double quote

I am not sure how to do both steps. Please help.

Comment: Why do you need to replace `'` by `\'` in double-quoted strings?

Comment: @melpomene I am not sure... if that is not required, please tell what is best way to convert this string, so that it can be loaded in json.loads

Comment: The other part you have to be careful about is double quotes in single-quoted strings: `'"'` needs to become `"\""`, not `"""`.

Comment: yeah... but how to do that..

Comment: I'd use a (slightly annoying to write) nested regex search/replace in Perl, but I don't know Python.

Comment: Are you trying to load a file's content? Do you have a file of dict? How did you write to the file?

Comment: I have a file of dicts (one dict i printed above). I have not generated this file... I got this data from somewhere else.

Comment: How about reading each line and use `ast.literal_eval` to convert the string  to dict?

Comment: @user3100115, u are awesome !!! worked like a charm... please post it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can't use the [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html#json.loads) function to deserialize your string because the string doesn't contain a valid JSON document. Instead, you should consider to use the [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) function.

Demo:

```
In [25]: import ast

In [26]: with open('inputfile') as f:
   ....:     for d in map(ast.literal_eval, f):
   ....:         print(d)
   ....:         
{'c': "abcd'efgh ijklm", 'a': 'b'}
{'c': "abcdgfgfgg", 'a': 'b'}
```